# ASP.NET - Problem with GridView with Dynamic Columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that includes BoundField and TemplateField elements. Some of the TemplateField elements are dynamically generated. For the sake of reference, here is the GridView that I am using

```
  <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      DataKeyNames="ID" ShowFooter="True" EnableModelValidation="True"
      OnLoad="myGridView_Load" OnRowCommand="myGridView_RowCommand"
      OnRowEditing="myGridView_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="myGridView_RowDeleting"  
      OnRowCancelingEdit="myGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
      OnRowUpdating="myGridView_RowUpdating">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" Visible="true" HeaderText="Test" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number">
          <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number") %>' />
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lb1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ftb" runat="server" Text="[x]" />
          </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <%-- Dynamically Generated Columns Will Be Inserted Here --%>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
          <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="ulb" runat="server" Text="update" CommandName="Update" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="clb" runat="server" Text="cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="slb" runat="server" Text="insert"  
              OnClick="saveLinkButton_Click" />
          </FooterTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="elb" runat="server" Text="edit" CommandName="Edit" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="dlb" runat="server" Text="delete" CommandName="Delete" />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField
   </Columns>                                                                                                                    
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td>Number</td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="ntb" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="slb2" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="saveLinkButton_Click" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>                                                                                
    </asp:GridView>
```

When the GridView initially loads, everything is loaded properly. However, anytime I perform a command (edit, insert, delete), all of the data goes away. Oddly, the BoundField values still appear correctly. However, any TemplateField does not seem to get rendered. The code that I am using to work with this GridView is here:

```
public partial class GridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<string> dynamicColumnNames = new List<string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadPageData();
    }

    protected void saveLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void myGridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            BindGridData();
        }
    }

    protected void myGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    { }

    protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        myGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGridData();
    }

    protected void myGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadPageData();
        BindGridData();
    }

    protected void myGridView_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGridData();
    }

    protected void myGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        myGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        LoadPageData();
        BindGridData();
    }

    private void BindGridData()
    {
        // Create a temporary data source
        DataTable tempData = new DataTable();
        tempData.Columns.Add("ID");
        tempData.Columns.Add("Number");           

        // Dynamically add template columns
        foreach (string columnName in dynamicColumnNames)
        {
            tempData.Columns.Add(columnName);

            TemplateField templateField = new TemplateField();
            templateField.HeaderTemplate = new MyTemplateField(ListItemType.Header, columnName);
            templateField.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplateField(ListItemType.Item, columnName);
            templateField.EditItemTemplate = new MyTemplateField(ListItemType.EditItem, columnName);
            templateField.FooterTemplate = new MyTemplateField(ListItemType.Footer, columnName);
            myGridView.Columns.Insert(2, templateField);
        }

        // Add some phony data
        Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow tempRow = tempData.NewRow();
            tempRow["Number"] = (i + 1);

            foreach (string column in dynamicColumnNames)
                tempRow[column] = random.NextDouble();
            tempData.Rows.Add(tempRow);
        }

        // Bind the data to the grid
        myGridView.DataSource = tempData;
        myGridView.DataBind();
    }

    private void LoadPageData()
    {
        dynamicColumnNames.Add("USA");
        dynamicColumnNames.Add("Japan");
        dynamicColumnNames.Add("Mexico");
    }
}

internal class MyTemplateField : ITemplate
{
    // The type of the list item
    private ListItemType listItemType;

    // The value to use during instantiation
    private string value1 = string.Empty;

    public MyTemplateField(ListItemType listItemType, string value1)
    {
        this.listItemType = listItemType;
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        if (listItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox.DataBinding += new EventHandler(textBox_DataBinding);
            container.Controls.Add(textBox);
        }
        else if (listItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.DataBinding += new EventHandler(textBox_DataBinding);
            container.Controls.Add(textBox);
        }
        else if (listItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            Literal literal = new Literal();
            literal.Text = value1;
            container.Controls.Add(literal);
        }
        else if (listItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            container.Controls.Add(textBox);
        }
    }

    private void textBox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)(sender);
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(textBox.NamingContainer);

        textBox.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, value1).ToString();
    }
}
```

How do I use commands in a GridView with Dynamically added columns? What is wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added controls must be added on each post, you can't just add these controls on the first page load. Try removing your `BindGridData()` from within the `Page.IsPostBack == false`.

Comment: I thought the same thing. Unfortunately though, that just causes the ListItemType.Item clause to get executed. However, the ListItemType.EditItem clause does not get executed. Because of this, this proposed solution does not fix the problem. Thank you for commenting though.

Comment: Is there any better way of dynamically populating template columns in gridview